# Mysterious white space between two divs

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out WHY there is a mysterious space appearing on the live version of my site but NOT on my local version.

Visit [this site](http://www.imadake.ca/about/).
Notice there's a gap above the div containing "imadake is an izakaya" which reveals the blue/white stripes of the background. On my local version of the site (with all the same files!) there is not gap.

I've tried multiple browsers and it consistently appears online, but not locally.

Help!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This seems like a straight-forward question with a straight-forward answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one possible reason is that questions on Stack Overflow should ideally be useful to others in the future. Once your problem is fixed, this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `<p></p>` above that title you recall. Check it out , maybe you're doing some kind of loop and the first iteration places an empty paragraph.

Comment: THANKS!
I was using a wordpress plugin that was adding the extra <p> after I updated the content. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a paragraph opening and closing at the top of the entry-content div with nothing in it.  Delete this and that should sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs may not be floating. Try placing a float left on each and you should see the strange gap go away.